# fails to import module when using matlabdomain

Tags: matlab, python-sphinx

While trying to use the sphinx matlab domain I can't get the MWE to work, provided on the [extensions pypi site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain)

There is always this `Can't import module` error. I'd guess, that the extension kind of generates pseudo modules from the m-code, but up to know I actually could not figure out, how this mechanism works.

The dir structure looks like this

```
root
   |--test_data
   |          |--MyHandleClass.m
   |
   |--doc
        |--------conf.py
        |--------Makefile
        |--------index.rst
```

The files `MyHandleClass.m` and `index.rst` contain the example code given on the [package site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain) and the `conf.py` starts like this

```
import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('./test_data'))    

# -- General configuration -----------------------------------------------------
# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be extensions
# coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom ones.
extensions = [
"sphinxcontrib.matlab",
"sphinx.ext.autosummary",
"sphinx.ext.autodoc"]

autodoc_default_flags = ['members','show-inheritance','undoc-members']
autoclass_content = 'both'

mathjax_path = 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default'

# The suffix of source filenames.
source_suffix = '.rst'

# The encoding of source files.
#source_encoding = 'utf-8'

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'
```

Error msg

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'test_data'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sphinx\ext\autodoc.py", line 335, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
ImportError: No module named test_data
E:\ME\doc\index.rst:13: WARNING: don't know which module to import for autodocumenting u'MyHandleClass' (try placing a "module" or "currentmodule" directive in the document, or giving an explicit module name)
```

After varying this and that maybe somebody out there has a clue?

Comment: Sorry, but evidently the `autosummary` extension will not work with the present version of `sphinxcontrib.matlabdomain`. I took a very brief look at it, and it may take a while for me to implement. If anyone else has the time, contributions are welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for trying the matlabdomain sphinxcontrib extension. In order to use Sphinx to document MATLAB m-files, you need to add `matlab_src_dir` in `conf.py` as described in the [Configuration](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain#configuration) section of the documenation. This is because the Python interpreter can't import a MATLAB m-file. Therefore you should **not** add your MATLAB root to the Python `sys.path`, or you will get the error you received. Instead set `matlab_src_dir` to the path containing the folder of your MATLAB project which you want to document.

Given your file structure, in order to document `test_data` use a `conf.py` with the following:

```
import os
# NOTE: don't add MATLAB m-files to `sys.path`
#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
# instead add them to `matlab_src_dir
matlab_src_dir = os.path.abspath('..')  # MATLAB
```

Hope that does it! Please feel free to ask any more questions. I'm happy to help!